# attachment_fu rmagick on phusion passenger

Tags: imagemagick, passenger, rmagick, attachment-fu, phusion

I am getting so much pain with setting up rmagick on Passenger . I’m developing a rails web application that has image processing feature using imagemagick. the image processing feature is working 100% on development using mongrel, but once i deploy it to production which uses phusion passenger I get the error

uninitialized constant Technoweenie::AttachmentFu::Processors::RMagickProcessor

i have successfully installed the following gems:

1.) rmagick (2.13.1)
2.) imagemagick

---

this is the code from the model

has_attachment :content_type => :image,

```
             :storage => :file_system,
             :processor => 'Rmagick',
             :resize_to => '300 x 400',
             :max_size => 2.megabytes,
             :thumbnails => { :thumb => [85, 95], :geometry => 'x50'}
```

---

Comment: Hi, Steven.  Did you find any solution to this problem?